# How to implement ./cloud_sql_proxy in GitHub Actions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, github-actions

```
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Download Cloud SQL Auth Proxy
      run: |
        wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy
        chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy

  job2:
    needs: job1
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: ./cloud_sql_proxy \
              -instances=...
```

I got this error:

> ./cloud_sql_proxy: No such file or directory

I wanna separate `job1` and `job2`.

How can I use `./cloud_sql_proxy` command in `job2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github jobs do not share files or data unless you take action to do so. One of the reasons is they can run in parallel on different systems/containers/computers.

There are several options. The easiest is to create a step in job2 that does the same download as the step in job1. Other options include workflow artifacts ([upload](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact) and [download](https://github.com/actions/download-artifact)) and [cache](https://github.com/actions/cache).